# Strange result when speed testing Math() in Firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, firefox

I got a strange result from a test I did (Firefox specific), and ***I would like to know more about how/why this is the result.***

A typical result looks like this (10 million list items) (I have run it several times manually, I didn't feel like making a full on "statistics module").

**Results for Firefox 72.0.2 (64-bit)** on Windows 7

```
iteration:  40 ms - timer stopped
__rounding: 14 ms - timer stopped
______ceil: 16 ms - timer stopped
_____floor: 15 ms - timer stopped
```

What I find most strange is the `iteration` test.

The "effective" `iteration` code looks like this: `arrNumbers[index] = arrNumbers[index];` and this code is part of ALL the tests, but the other parts have a `Math` function wrapped around the right part.

So it seams like the `iteration` test should dictate the speed for all other tests, I expected this part to be fastest, not slowest.

First I thought this was a "problem" with floating point numbers possibly being slower to process than integers, so I tried to just assign a `1` (int) so every function works on equal data, but the result is still the same.

---

**Code:**
(will probably not run here since I'm using `console.time()` I guess. But you can just copy it as is, to a text file & change the file extension to `.html` & open it with Firefox, press F12 to open the inspection tool & switch to the `Console` tab if needed).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

            function makeNrArray(loopSize) {
                var arrNumbers = [];
                for (let index = 0; index < loopSize; index++) {
                    arrNumbers[index] = 1; //Math.random();
                }
                return arrNumbers ; 
            }

            function testIterationSpeed(arrNumbers) {
                var arrLength = arrNumbers.length;

                console.time("iteration");
                for (let index = 0; index < arrLength; index++) {
                    arrNumbers[index] = arrNumbers[index];
                }
                console.timeEnd("iteration");
            }

            function testRoundingSpeed(arrNumbers) {
                var arrLength = arrNumbers.length;

                console.time("rounding");
                for (let index = 0; index < arrLength; index++) {
                    arrNumbers[index] = Math.round(arrNumbers[index]);
                }
                console.timeEnd("rounding");
            }

            function testCeilingSpeed(arrNumbers) {
                var arrLength = arrNumbers.length;

                console.time("ceil");
                for (let index = 0; index < arrLength; index++) {
                    arrNumbers[index] = Math.ceil(arrNumbers[index]);
                }
                console.timeEnd("ceil");
            }

            function testFlooringSpeed(arrNumbers) {
                var arrLength = arrNumbers.length;

                console.time("floor");
                for (let index = 0; index < arrLength; index++) {
                    arrNumbers[index] = Math.floor(arrNumbers[index]);
                }
                console.timeEnd("floor");
            }


            var loopSize = 10000000; // <---- Settings ;)

            let arrNumbers = makeNrArray(loopSize);
            testIterationSpeed(arrNumbers);

            arrNumbers = makeNrArray(loopSize);
            testRoundingSpeed(arrNumbers)

            arrNumbers = makeNrArray(loopSize);
            testCeilingSpeed(arrNumbers);

            arrNumbers = makeNrArray(loopSize);
            testFlooringSpeed(arrNumbers);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Other results:**

**Results for Firefox 72.0.2 (64-bit)** (Same as above, just for completeness & ease of comparison)

```
iteration:  40 ms - timer stopped
__rounding: 14 ms - timer stopped
______ceil: 16 ms - timer stopped
_____floor: 15 ms - timer stopped
```

**Firefox again,** but now assigned 1.5 (`float`) as input data (instead of `int`, as above)
(Math.random() gives a similar result)

```
iteration:  67 ms - timer stopped
__rounding: 33 ms - timer stopped
______ceil: 34 ms - timer stopped
_____floor: 32 ms - timer stopped
```

**Results for Google Chrome Version 80.0.3987.106 (64 bit)**

```
iteration:  11.7060546875   ms
__rounding: 12.194091796875 ms
______ceil: 11.73681640625  ms
_____floor: 11.551025390625 ms
```

**Results for Internet Explorer 11.0.9600..... Update: 11.0**

```
iteration:   37,3 ms
__rounding: 203,5 ms
______ceil:  85,9 ms
_____floor:  85,7 ms
```

Comment: It's likely down to boxing & type tests, when you do `Math.trunc(), ceil()` etc, the JS engine knows in advance the result is going to be an integer,. But for your iteration it's going to have to do a type test, it doesn't know in advance if the results is going to be a float / integer / object or anything else, this can take time.

Comment: **@Keith** I tried the suggestion from **Tmdesigned** to duplicate my first test, and it turns out it is some kind of "first time loading into memory" thing that makes it slower, the 2'nd time I run the same test with the same data, then it has nearly identical speed as the other tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually the order you are running the tests, I believe.

First of all, the results aren't that dramatic for me. In Chrome they're almost identical, and in Firefox I see a small--but consistent--increase in time on your iteration test. Usually it's around 5-15ms longer, but it's consistent, so I'll give it to you that it's real.

If you add a `Math.floor()` to the iteration test, you'll *still* see higher numbers here.

But if you move the iteration test to the end, like this:

```
let arrNumbers = makeNrArray(loopSize);
testRoundingSpeed(arrNumbers)

arrNumbers = makeNrArray(loopSize);
testCeilingSpeed(arrNumbers);

arrNumbers = makeNrArray(loopSize);
testFlooringSpeed(arrNumbers);

arrNumbers = makeNrArray(loopSize);
testIterationSpeed(arrNumbers);
```

Then you'll see the `testIterationSpeed` result go down to the range of the others, while the `testRoundingSpeed` will go up.

I suspect it has something to do with the allocation of memory, since the subsequent results use the same variable (well, the same `let`). I don't know the details. Regardless, it is less about what you are doing and more about when.

Comment: AHA! So I should run a "bogus" test first, just to make everything load into memory first? (alternatively, use different array variables for each test?)

Comment: **HAH! Yes!** I just duplicated the ```itterationTest``` & it went from 45ms to 13ms, just like the other tests (+/- 1ms)

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. I'd call it "spin-up" or something.

Comment: Just for the record of how DAMN fast a computer is, it takes 14 ms to iterate through 10 MILLION items, that makes it only spend 1.4 NANO Seconds per item (on average) :O